# Segfault when allocating memory with custom allocation implementation; works for all sizes but 8 bytes

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I've got a custom allocation for an assignment and am almost done. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem I cannot seem to diagnose. The allocation is handled by two functions which do cache allocations (< 2kB) and region allocations (> 2kB). Here are my memory structs:

```
 23 typedef struct slab {
 24         void *addr;
 25         int bm[SLAB_SIZE/8/(8*sizeof(int))]; // bitmap for the slab
 26         struct slab *next;
 27 } slab;

 40 typedef struct {
 41         int alloc_unit;
 42         slab S;
 43 } cache;


 46 typedef struct { // structure for the entire memory
 47         cache C[9];
 48         region *R;
 49 } memory;
```

(Note: The bitmap is the same size for all slabs, a bit inefficient but I wanted to get it working like this first instead of have tons of duplicate code everywhere)

The problem resides in the rather complex allocate_cache function which *works for all allocations above 8 bytes*. I have tested it somewhat intensely by allocating 50-100k instances of 16B, 32B, ... 2kB, and everything worked fine. The logic is as following: each `cache` contains a single `slab` at the start. Each `slab` can have `SLAB_SIZE/alloc_unit slots` in it, which differs for different slabs (so 2kB slabs can contain up to 32 slots of 2kB memory in it, 1kB slabs contain 64 slots, and so on).

Here's my allocate cache function:

```
 55 void *allocate_cache(unsigned int size) { // cache allocation
 56
 57         // 1. Select the cache
 58         int ci = 0, si, pos, bmi; // cache_index, slot_index, position, bitmap index
 59         int slbn = 0; // slab number
 60         unsigned short check = 0;
 61         while ((size-1) >> (ci+3))
 62                 ci++;
 63         // 2. Find a slot
 64         bmi = 0; // bitmap index
 65         int lbmi = 0; // 'linked' bitmap index
 66         int counter = 0;
 67         int coefficient = SLAB_SIZE/M.C[ci].alloc_unit;
 68         do {
 69                 pos = find_zero_bit(M.C[ci].S.bm[bmi]); // Find the first zero bit in the bitmap
 70                 if (pos == -1) { bmi++; // If bm[bmi] does not have free slots, keep checking the map...
 71                         if(bmi == coefficient/(8*sizeof(int))){ // If bmi is max size, then we need to check
 72                                 slab *next_slab = &M.C[ci].S;            // the following slabs, if there are any.
 73                                 while(next_slab->next != NULL){ // While there are additional slabs
 74                                         next_slab = next_slab->next;
 75                                         slbn++; // Increment the slab counter.
 76                                         while(lbmi < bmi) { // Go through the slots in this slab too
 77                                                 pos = find_zero_bit(next_slab->bm[lbmi]); // Until a free slot has been found
 78                                                 if(pos != -1) { // If a free slot has been found...
 79                                                         set_bit(&(next_slab->bm[lbmi]), pos); // Mark it as occupied...
 80                                                         check = 1;
 81                                                         break;  // And break out of the loop.
 82                                                 }
 83                                         lbmi++; counter++;
 84                                         }
 85                                 if(check == 1) break; // If we already found a free slot in one of the slots, break.
 86                                 lbmi = 0;
 87                                 }
 88                         }
 89                 }
 90                 else break;
 91         } while(bmi < coefficient/(8*sizeof(int)));
 92         si = bmi*32 + counter*32 + (pos - 1);
 93         // compute the slot index based on bmi,  pos and counter
 94         // 3.a Slot not found => allocate a new slab
 95         printf("pos = %d , si = %d, bmi = %d, slbn = %d lbmi = %d counter = %d\n", pos, si, bmi, slbn, lbmi, counter); // sanity check
 96         if(pos == 32 && ((si+1) % coefficient == 0)) {
 97                 printf("===== SLAB FULL. NOW CREATING NEW SLAB. =====\n");
 98                 // Initialize a new slab.
 99                 slab *temp = &M.C[ci].S; // Set temp to the initially allocated slab
100                 while(temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next; // Get the last currently allocated slab
101                 void *new_addr = mmap(NULL, SLAB_SIZE + sizeof(slab), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
102                 slab *new_slab = new_addr;
103                 new_slab->addr = (char *)new_addr + sizeof(slab);
104                 temp->next = new_slab; // Set the new slab as the one following the existing slabs
105                 temp->next->addr = new_slab->addr; // Set the new slab's address to the newly mmap'd address
106                 temp->next->next = NULL; // Set the new slab's NEXT pointer to NULL
107                 bzero(&new_slab->bm, SLAB_SIZE/M.C[ci].alloc_unit/8); // Zero-out the new slab's bitmap
108                 if(temp->addr == MAP_FAILED) { // Check if mmap succeeded...
109                         printf("mmap failed. Exiting...\n");
110                         exit(-1);
111                 }
112                 printf("Allocated memory for cache %d's slab %d  at address %p\n", ci, slbn, temp->next);
113         }
114         printf("Use cache %d , slab %d (allocation unit size: %d)\n", ci, slbn,M.C[ci].alloc_unit);
115         printf("Found slot %d in slab %d of cache %d\n", si % (SLAB_SIZE/M.C[ci].alloc_unit), slbn, ci);
116
117         // 3.b Slot found
118
119         if(M.C[ci].S.addr == NULL) { // Slab not allocated yet
120                 M.C[ci].S.addr = mmap(NULL, SLAB_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
121                 printf("Allocated memory for cache %d's slab at address %p\n", ci, M.C[ci].S.addr);
122         }
123
124         if(M.C[ci].S.addr == MAP_FAILED) {
125                 perror("mmap failed\n");
126                 exit(-1);
127         }
128         set_bit(&M.C[ci].S.bm[bmi], pos); // mark the bit as occupied
129
130         // 4. Return address
131
132         return M.C[ci].S.addr + si*M.C[ci].alloc_unit;
133 }
```

The offending line seems to be `line 77`. Running GDB gives me the following results:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400847 in allocate_cache (size=5) at allocator.c:77
77 pos = find_zero_bit(next_slab->bm[lbmi]); // Until a free slot has been found
```

However, I don't see how this could be the case. `next_slab` is correctly initialized (`line 101-111`, and bm is a bitmap which is zeroed out using bzero (`line 107`). Therefore, I'm inclined to believe that this is a different issue and just pops up at line 107, but I have not been able to diagnose it for a few days.

I have also been going through my logic to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid like overwriting slab struct addresses, but to my knowledge the range that mmap supplies me with does not allow this to happen.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Please let me know if you like me to reformat the code in any way. I realize it might be a little unsightly.

**Edit**: Cache initialization at the start is done in my `init_memory()` function. The lines pertinent to caches are the following:

```
161         // Init the caches
162         for(i =0; i<9; i++) {
163                 M.C[i].alloc_unit = 8<<i;
164                 M.C[i].S.addr = NULL;
165                 M.C[i].S.next = NULL;
166                 bzero(M.C[i].S.bm, SLAB_SIZE/M.C[i].alloc_unit/8);
167         }
```

**UPDATE**: It seems I have found the error. It was a logic error more than anything else. My bitmaps arrays had a size of 256, that is 0..255. In the case of 8 byte allocations, the bitmap correctly was set to 256 to signify that the last free slot was being used up, but this conflicted with the definition of my bitmap, for which bm[256] is an illegal read. Hence, undefined behaviour. I fixed the issue by simply increasing the size of the bitmap array by 1, i.e. `int bm[((SLAB_SIZE/8)/(8*sizeof(int)))+1];`.

Many thanks to Koushik, who helped me in trying to figure this out. The parentheses he suggested I add in a few places have probably saved me a few debugging headaches down the road as well.

Comment: i see that you are not incrementing `lbmi`? in `while(lbmi < bmi)`? if you find empty slot and break good but if you dont?. it will search the same slot again and again infinitely.

Comment: I increment `lbmi` in `line 83`, along with `counter`. They serve to get the correct slot position when there is more than one slab.

Comment: yeah that you do after the while loop? you have to increment  within the while loop, otherwise how will you check the next slot? that while is from 76 - 82.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my indentation needs some work there. The `while` spans lines 76-84, and includes the incrementing. The inner `if` spans from 78-82, and those are the braces you are referring to.

Comment: `M.C[ci].S` is initialized?can you paste that code?

Comment: I added a few pertinent lines from my `init_memory()` function, but either way `M.C[ci].S->addr` itself (the `slab` address) is initialized the first time the code is run in lines `119-122`.

Comment: 1 question. the first time you enter the `do` do you expect line 73 `next_slab->next` to be `NULL`? i.e before the `M.C[ci].S` is initialized?sorry i'm having a hard time breaking your code:-)

Comment: you have initialized `S` but not not S.next. atleast i dont see it anywhere. Here is the scenario. you initialize `M.C[ci].S` after the fist `do`,when this happens the next_slab->next need not be `NULL`. then you dereference it. this causes seg fault.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting for my last edit screwed up. I added my `init_memory()` function correctly this time. That takes care of initializing `M.C[ci].S->next` to `NULL` (line `165`). And yes, I expect it to be `NULL` the first time I am in the `do ... while`, up until the first slab has been filled up. Again, apologies for the misshap.

Comment: ah there is where you find Undefined behaviour. yes you initialize to `NULL` **after** the first time `do` executes. inside `do` you dereference the S.next(which is not `NULL` but `anything`aka UB). then you enter the while and initialize the S.next. since it is `Anything` line 73 while() is satisfied for the first time. check by printing the address of S.next when you enter the function. please go through your code i hope what i'm saying is clear.

Comment: Ah, you are correct! I stepped through it and this was the case: `next should be NULL/(nil). It is: 0x7f91cdbe2001`. Great catch! Could you please post it as an answer so that I may accept it? It isn't a solution, but it's far more than I started with and a great lead.

Comment: dint the initialization(init_memory()) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems something weird is happening with `M.C[ci].S.next`.

Comment: no prob lets solve it now. lets continue in the answer part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem : segmentation fault.

cause : pointer not initialized.

where and which :

line 72 :

```
slab *next_slab = &M.C[ci].S;
```

here `M.C[ci].S.next` was supposed to be `NULL` upon entry into the

```
void *allocate_cache(unsigned int size)
```

where was the dereferencing done? :

Line 77:

```
pos = find_zero_bit(next_slab->bm[lbmi]);
```

reason for a true case in :

```
while(next_slab->next != NULL)
```

**Undefined behaviour**. since `next_slab->next` was not initialized.

another note :

```
#define PAGE_SIZE 1024 better be #define PAGE_SIZE (1024)
#define SLAB_SIZE 16*PAGE_SIZE should be #define SLAB_SIZE (16*(PAGE_SIZE))
```

reason : line 67(also other places)

```
int coefficient = SLAB_SIZE/M.C[ci].alloc_unit; is interpreted as
int coefficient = 16*1024/M.C[ci].alloc_unit;
```

here multiplication and division have same precedence.

Comment: @user991710 now to solve this case. did you check what the value of `ci` is (line 62)? is `M` a global?

Comment: `M` is a global, declared as `memory M;`. The value of `ci` in the offending case is, as expected, 0, since we are dealing with cache 0 which contains 8 byte slots.

Comment: can you comment out the `bzero` line and check?are you still getting segfault at that line?

Comment: Yes, will do. I believe I found the root of the issue. The first time I enter the inner while loop, as you said, `M.C[ci].S.next` is `anything`. However, I specifically prevent `M.C[ci].S.next' to be anything but NULL through line `165` in my `init_memory()` function. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: is there any other code after init_memory() and allocate_cashe() that access `M`?

Comment: There is not, unfortunately. I've uploaded all relevant code here: [allocator.c](http://ideone.com/EEjxYH), [bits.c](http://ideone.com/8P1qoq) (only find_zero_bit is used from here), [main.c](http://ideone.com/7NZEiR).

Comment: which compiler and what version are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc: `gcc --version gcc (GCC) 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)`. If you wish, here is an all-in-one file that includes all sources (should compile OK, ideone can't run it because it uses /dev/zero): http://ideone.com/WfLuUL

Comment: there is one other mistake i saw in your code. SLAB_SIZE shoulde be define with parantheses(check my edit).

Comment: i got some output when i ran the code after commenting the file opening part in init_memory(). what is that?

Comment: The file descriptor merely uses /dev/zero to map zeroes to memory. The  output I got was simply that mmap failed. I've corrected the parentheses, but am still seeing some weird things. I'm stepping through right now to note where exactly everything goes to hell! Thank you very much for your continued efforts!

Comment: yeah sure. now it time for me to sleep its 3.34 am here:-).please edit the question with the answer. i'l check ack tomorrow.

Comment: I fixed the issue! Your parentheses catch led me to something else, which in turn led me to the source of the issue. Since you were quite helpful, I will gladly accept your answer. Thank you. =)